# Javascript (function (){})() closure

Tags: javascript

Can any one explain why this happens?

```
// Example 1
(function () {
    var a = b = 5;
})();

console.log(b); // Output 5
```

`var a = b = 5` and `var b = 5` is totally different?

Comment: `var a = b = 5;` is like `b = 5; var a = 5;`

Comment: var a = b = 5; means var a = 5; and window.b =5; thats why b is accessible outside IIFE.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to use `const` or `let` instead of `var`, and move to [JavaScript modules](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) or at least enable [strict mode](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). The syntax for a declaration like `var` consists of a _VariableDeclarationList_ after the keyword. You have one _VariableDeclaration_ which consists of _BindingIdentifier Initializer_. The _BindingIdentifier_ is `a`, the _Initializer_ is the `=` followed by the _AssignmentExpression_ `b = 5`. `b` was never a _BindingIdentifier_.